# where is the built in mic on Asus ROG GL752 laptop

Tags: laptop, microphone

My mic is not working or it's really faded want to check it out maybe replace it but cant figure out were it's located.

I'm not talking about the microphone jack

Is it located in the screen frame?

Comment: "Normally, the Microphone is located on either side of the laptop camera"

Comment: [[Notebook] Troubleshooting - How to fix the Sound (Speakers/Microphones) problems on ASUS laptops | Official Support | ASUS UK](https://www.asus.com/uk/support/FAQ/1015070/)